# Glassfish doc root URI patterns are not resolving

Tags: glassfish

I have a Glassfish server working on windows and a problem with alternatedocroot. When I use this

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/9075.png dir=C:\member\"/>
```

and request server:8080/myapp/images/9075.png the correct file is displayed. However the directory is full of images so I have tried all of these at different times

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/\*.png dir=C:\member\"/>
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/*.png dir=C:\member\"/>
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/\* dir=C:\member\"/>
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=C:\member\"/>
```

but the same request (server:8080/myapp/images/9075.png) produces a 404 error. I am sure I am making a silly error but I can't see it. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=C:\\member\\"/>
```

This may have to do with windows back-slashes requires escaping.